# Correct Normalization for Players to Match

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, normalization

Each match has 14 players.

I currently have it so that I enter 14 entries into the match table like so:

```
matchID    bookingID    playerID
1          1            1
1          1            2
1          1            3
1          1            4
```

etc.

Would this be okay or would it be more acceptable to do it like so:

```
matchID    bookingID    playerID1    playerID2    playerID3    playerID4
1          1            1            2            3            4
```

Comment: You want to switch from a normalized structure to a worst one. As far as i'm concerned, this is okay, this is not my code, but since you know about normalization, just stick with it ! Your second code is only ok to use if you're sure there is and will always be 14 players for 1 match. But even then, you can't call that normalized, just bad design that happens to work.

Answer (score 0):

No, "normalization" in this context means you would want to create multiple tables, `Match`, `MatchPlayer`, `Booking`, and `Player` that relate to one another based on their primary keys.  For example:

`Match` table:

```
MatchID    BookingID
---------------------
```

`PlayerMatch` table:

```
MatchID    PlayerID
-------------------
```

`Booking` table:

```
BookingID
----------
```

`Player` table:

```
PlayerID
--------
```

Now the `MatchID` is the primary key in the `Match` table and it's the foreign key in the `MatchPlayer` table, and the `PlayerID` is the primary key in the `Player` table and it's the foreign key in the `MatchPlayer` table.  This creates a "many to many" relationship between matches and players because there can be multiple matches in which a player can participate, and there are obviously multiple players in a given match.

Also, the `BookingID` is the primary key in the `Booking` table and it's the foreign key in the `Match` table, and in this case, there is a "one to many" relationship between bookings and matches because there can be multiple matches at each booking.

This approach allows you, for example, to have **one** record per player so you can have additional information about a player without repeating that information unnecessarily in the `Match` table, like first name, last name, age, gender, etc.  Similarly, it allows you to have **one** record that holds information about a booking, like date, venue name, etc.

Given your current example, normalization would seem to be unnecessary since you don't have any additional information about players and bookings, but it seems like your schema could quickly expand to involve more information.

Comment: Ah sorry I should have confirmed I have more than just this table.

My tables are

matches - matchID bookingID playerID
players - names, contact, etc
bookings - venue, date etc

I already have a table set up similar to what you've described here I just wasn't sure on what would be the best input for players to match.

Would it be wise to keep my current format for matches table or should I switch it to remove the MM relationship is what I was asking... Must remember to make my questions cleaer!

Comment: Also, there can't be more than one match per booking, so should the match table just be bookingID and playerID and scrap the matchID?

Comment: Well, now that's a different question.  There's always been a debate about whether to have what's called a "surrogate" key or to use a "composite" key.  You'd have to google it and decide what's best for you.  For what it's worth, I always use surrogate keys to be consistent.

Comment: So in this case is the current system the best way to keep track of my players to matches?

I really feel like having the bookingID and matchID repeated over and over being bad normalization, but I'm not to this stuff.